# VLC Streaming video from ip camera

Tags: streaming, vlc, ip-camera

Using the vlc interface I am able to stream the video from my ip-camera, but now I need to do it by command line. At least I can open the video using this command line `cvlc 'http://192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd='` but this command line only reproduce the video, I need the stream from the VLC.

When I use the VLC interface for streamming, it gives me this command line byt its interface `:sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100} :duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg},dst=display} :sout-keep`

To summarize, my final command line is as follows:

```
cvlc 'http://192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=' :sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100} :duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg},dst=display} :sout-keep
```

But it does not work, any idea?

Comment: Solved, the following script by command line works for me:

`vlc "http://192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=" --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg},dst=display}" --sout-keep`



If you are in Linux, you also can use cvlc instead of vlc. With this streaming I am able to use it in OpenCV with the following function `cap=cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg")`

Answer (score -2):

```
cvlc "http://10.0.0.10:8181/video"
```

That's al there is to it.